# Using .htaccess to redirect a certain file type from root to a sub folder

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect a certain file type (PDF) from root to a sub folder, but I'm not sure how to limit the rule so that only requests for PDF files in the root are redirected while any requests for files in sub folders are left untouched.

Example: 
A request for **www.mydomain.com/myfile.pdf** should be rewritten to **www.mydomain.com/pdfs/myfile.pdf**, 
but a request for **www.mydomain.com/other_folder/otherfile.pdf** should not be redirected.

The file name can vary, but it should only apply to PDF files.

I've gotten this far, which seems to work for the first part but also means that PDFs in sub folders are being rewritten...

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.pdf$ pdfs/$1.pdf [NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.pdf$ pdfs/$1.pdf [NC,L]
```

PS: this is internal redirect, if you want external redirect, use:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.pdf$ pdfs/$1.pdf [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer :)